# Please explain why I'm not getting a value error 100% of the time?

Tags: python, dataframe

When I use the following code I selectively see a map or get the error `ValueError: cannot insert Cluster Labels, already exists`. Could someone please explain? Additionally, I used the term "lable" and that worked somewhat too. Something is odd here.

```
# add clustering labels
neighbourhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_)

toronto_merged = df_toronto

# merge toronto_grouped with toronto_data to add latitude/longitude for each neighborhood
toronto_merged = toronto_merged.join(neighborhoods_venues_sorted.set_index('Neighbourhood'), on='Neighbourhood')

toronto_merged.head() # check the last columns!
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: What are you inserting from? What are you inserting into? If you're using pandas, please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/dd1223c0-0f64-48e5-b682-bc05c0b9777a/view?access_token=be5a2624be34d810b2c23d27d328024ab1b5bf6a94065cbecbab976d46c394ab